# Background-image Path using Sass with Gulp

Tags: html, css, sass

My background-image is not loading!
I searched stackoverflow for a solution but the stuff I found didn't solve my specific problem.

I use GULP as a build tool, the GULP SASS Compiler for SASS compiling and GULP BROWSER-SYNC as testserver.

My html

```
<section class="img_header">
 <div class="text_img_header_centered">
  <h1>blabla</h1> 
  <h2>blablablabla</h2>
</div>
</section>
```

My CSS:

```
.img_header {
  background-image: url('/assets/img/flugzeug_375x667.jpg');
}
```

[image: file-structure]

That's my file structure. main.css in folder css. blabla.jpg in img (as seen in the picture). My main.scss is in the dev-folder. Website is not online yet. But the background-image is not loading!. Any ideas? Only have one css-file included in this project. All other properties work just fine.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's likely a path problem. But before we can help you, we need to know more about the project. Are you using a build tool like Webpack? What do you use to process the SCSS into CSS? All that stuff can have an impact on paths.

Comment: Also, you'll need a webserver running to use `/` as root. Your file system doesn't know what that is. Remember that paths in CSS are relative to the page reading the file not to the CSS file itself. Simply removing the first / might fix the problem but I don't know where your HTML files are relative to the site root.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your replies. Great community. I will be more precise. I use **gulp** as a build tool. My SCSS Compiler is **Gulp Sass**. I am using the gulp-tool **browser-sync**. My index.html (which demands the picture) is in the root of the site-folder on the same lvl as the assets-folder. (please check my picture9 "file-structure" in the main-thread to see information about the the whole file-structure). I want to use the background-image for a header covering one screen size and I want to use the background-image features to cover the container with the picture. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see the indention very well, but I think it's something like this.

```
.img_header {
  background-image: url('../../../assets/img/flugzeug_375x667.jpg');
}
```

In the future, you should try using a public folder and incorporating that into your build using something like Webpack. You could also use an absolute path if your file is served over the Internet.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I am using **Gulp** with the tools **Gulp Sass** and **browser-sync** (as a test server). I edited the thread to explain my problem more precisely. I also wrote a comment as seen above. Unfortunately I still couldnt find a solution :(

Comment: @MarqueedeLuxe This is just an opinion, but Gulp is sort of outdated. You should try moving to another bundler like Webpack or CRA if you're building React apps.

Comment: Thanks for your request. Do you know a good tutorial about how to get started with webpack? Because I dont have much experience with that stuff. Still I wonder why my background doesnt work.

Comment: Found the mistake. It was a problem with the height of the container. The div just collapsed because there was no content inside :-/. Now I have set a height: 100 vh and the image is shown well.

Comment: @MarqueedeLuxe lol for future reference, you can use the Dev tools to see if it loaded under the Network tab or you can just hover over the path in the Elements tab and it should pop up (Chrome).